# Testing copatibility of own program without changing device or uninstalling IDE

Tags: python, testing, compatibility

*Intro (unimportant):*
I am new to programming (and to stackoverflow) and just completed a small Python course. I used one of the last completed exercises in the course as a base to write a simple program. It works as I want it and I tried to make it as foolproof as possible. I tried researching the problem below, but couldn't find an answer (maybe my wording is incorrect).

**Problem:**

I know I can use Python installer, Nuitka or other tools to compile the code into an .exe, desirably as a stand alone program not needing python or other programming softare installed. This process I noticed is not 100%, as after sending it to a family member, they couldn't open the file.

Is there a way to test if the program I created works on its own (on an end user PC without special software), using my own PC and without uninstalling the programming software?

*For those interested in my code:*
It's a game without any graphics (just typing) with 3 difficulty settings, where first the program tries to guess your number, then you try to guess the number of the code, then the code compares the number of tries and tells you who won. It asks you if you want to play again.
As the course was in German language, the print() and input() outputs are in German. I will certainly also be happy about any tips for improvement (I hope I entered the code correctly):

```
from random import randint
from time import sleep
name = input("Hallo, wie heißt du? (Gib deinen Namen ein und drücke Enter): ")
print(f"Danke {name}, lass uns jetzt ein spiel spielen.")
sleep(2)
print(" ")
print("In Runde 1, überlegst du dir eine Zahl zwischen 1 und 100 und ich versuche die zu erraten.")
sleep(3)
print("Ich gebe dir eine Zahl und du schreibst 'r' wenn richtig, 'k' wenn deine Zahl kleiner ist und 'g' wenn deine Zahl größer ist.")
sleep(4)
input("ok?: ")
print(" ")
print("In Runde 2, überlege ich mir eine Zahl und du musst die erraten.")
sleep(3)
print("Schreibe einfach eine Nummer und ich sage dir ob meine Zahl größer, kleiner oder richtig ist.")
sleep(4)
input("ok?: ")
print(" ")


nochmal = "ja"
while nochmal == "ja" or nochmal == "yes" or nochmal == "shi" or nochmal == "ok" or nochmal == "y" or     nochmal == "j":
    level = input("Bitte gib eine gewünschte schwierigkeit ein; 'normal', 'schwer' oder 'extrem'?: ")
    if level == 'schwer' or level == 's' or level == 'schwierig':
        zahl = randint(49,51)
        zahl2 = randint(1, 100)
        print("Schierigkeit für diese Runde: schwer")
    elif level == 'extrem' or level == 'extreme' or level == 'e' or level == 'ex':
        zahl = randint(48,52)
        zahl2 = randint(1, 300)
        print("Schierigkeit für diese Runde: extrem. In Runde 2, musst du eine Zahl zwischen 1 und 300 raten.")
        sleep(1.5)
    else:
        zahl = randint(25,75)
        zahl2 = randint(1, 100)
        print("Schierigkeit für diese Runde: normal")
    print(" ")
    sleep(1.5)
    print("Fangen wir an mit Runde 1 an. Bitte nur einen von den Buchstaben 'r', 'k' oder 'g' eingeben.")
    sleep(3)
    print(" ")


    liste = list(range(1, 101))
    count = 1
    count2 = 1
    while True:
        frage = input(f"Ist {zahl} richtig?").lower()
        if frage == "r":
            sleep(1)
            break
        elif frage == "g":
            try:
                for nr in range((zahl + 1) - liste[0]):
                    liste.pop(0)
                zahl = randint(liste[0], liste[-1])
                count = count + 1
            except IndexError:
                print("Die Antwort kann nicht höher sein, da alle höheren Zahlen schon ausgeschlossen sind")
        elif frage == "k":
            try:
                for nr in range(liste[-1] - (zahl-1)):
                    liste.pop()
                zahl = randint(liste[0], liste[-1])
                count = count + 1
            except IndexError:
                print("Die Antwort kann nicht niedriger sein, da alle höheren Zahlen schon ausgeschlossen sind")
        else:
            antwort = randint(1,3)
            if antwort == 1:
                print("HEY! Ich habe doch gesagt nur eines der 3 Buchstaben einzugeben!")
                sleep(1)
                print(" ")
                sleep(0.5)
            elif antwort == 2:
                print("Ungültige Engabe, bitte nur eines von den 3 oben genannten Buchstaben eingeben.")
                sleep(1)
                print(" ")
                sleep(0.5)
            else:
                print("Nur eines der Buchstaben 'r' (richtig) 'k' (deine Zahl ist kleiner) oder 'g'(deine Zahl ist größer) gilt als richtige Eingabe.")
                sleep(1.5)
                print(" ")
                sleep(0.5)
    if count == 1:
        print(f"Ich habe die richtige zahl in {count} runde erraten.")
    else:
        print(f"Ich habe die richtige zahl in {count} runden erraten.")
    print(" ")
    sleep(2)


    if level == 'extrem' or level == 'extreme' or level == 'e' or level == 'ex':
        print("Fangen wir mit Runde 2 an. Versuche meine Zahl zwischen 1 und 300 zu erraten.")
    else:
        print("Fangen wir mit Runde 2 an. Versuche meine Zahl zwischen 1 und 100 zu erraten.")
    sleep(2)
    print(" ")
    sleep(0.5)
    zahl2 = randint(1, 100)
    while True:
        try:
            if level == 'extrem' or level == 'extreme' or level == 'e' or level == 'ex':
                eingabe = int(input("Gib eine Zahl zwischen 1-300 ein: "))
            else:
                eingabe = int(input("Gib eine Zahl zwischen 1-100 ein: "))
            if eingabe == zahl2:
                sleep(1)
                print(" ")
                if count2 == 1:
                    print(f"WOW, hast wohl Glück gehabt. Du hast nur einen Versuch gebraucht")
                    sleep(1.5)
                elif count2 == 2 or count2 == 3 or count2 == 4:
                    print(f"WOW! Du hast nur {count2} Versuche gebraucht!")
                    sleep(1)
                else:
                    print(f"Du hast {count2} Versuche gebraucht.")
                break
            elif zahl2 > eingabe:
                sleep(0.5)
                print("Zu klein")
                print(" ")
                sleep(1)
                count2 = count2 + 1
            else:
                sleep(0.5)
                print("Zu groß")
                print(" ")
                sleep(1)
                count2 = count2 + 1
        except ValueError:
            sleep(0.5)
            print("Falsche Eingabe, bitte eine ganze Zahl eingeben.")


    if count < count2:
        print(" ")
        sleep(1)
        print(f"Ich habe diese Runde gewonnen, sorry {name}.")
    elif count == count2:
        print(" ")
        sleep(1)
        print("Wir haben die gleiche Anzahl von Versuchen benutzt.")
    else:
        print(" ")
        sleep(1)
        print(f"Herzlichen Glückwunsch {name}, du hast gewonnen!")
    print(" ")
    sleep(1.5)
    nochmal = input(f"Noch ein Spiel {name}? ").lower()
    print(" ")
print(f"Danke fürs Spielen {name}!")
sleep(1.5)
quit()
```

Comment: Does it gives an error when they try to open it? Are they on the same OS as you? Please be a bit more specific

Comment: Both Win10, gives a message (not a cross with 'Error' written) that cannot be opened due to sth missing that the program tries to access (all the required files are present). I didn't want to bother more, so I don't have the exact message. This is however not my question, as I just want to know how to test it on my PC as if python and visual studio are not installed (without uninstalling). Then I can do multiple tries and research every error message, without wasting time or bothering anyone.

Comment: Oh. You could use a Windows VM. https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/downloads/virtual-machines/

Comment: Wow, amazing thx! I will check it out tomorrow.

Comment: @Seth I got VM Ware and this virtual machine and it's exactly what I needed. Thank you for the tip.